# MongoDB retrieve every document contained in another document's array

Tags: javascript, mongodb, mongodb-stitch

I'm new to MongoDB so this might be a basic question but I am having trouble in how to approach it.

I want to find one document in my collection, like so:

```
db.collection("articles").find({curid:"1000143"}).asArray();
```

One of the fields returned is an array containing other document's 'curid' (a unique value):

```
HDP_Topics = ["1124516", "101388", "1031462", "1053284", "1077080", "1150760", "1092377", "1100194", "1103692", "1135134", "1134909", "1119820", "1000634", "1120316", "1000143"]
```

What I want to do is to find each of these other documents and append them onto the already existing find query results. I'm sure there must be a way without having make a new search for every element in the array.

(I'm using mongoDB Atlas's Stitch if that makes any difference)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand the question correctly, you want to use the HDP_Topics field to trigger a new search. You can use a [$graphLookup](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/graphLookup/#examples) for this:

```
db.articles.aggregate( [
   {
      $graphLookup: {
         from: "articles",
         startWith: "1000143",
         connectFromField: "HDP_Topics",
         connectToField: "curid",
         as: "otherDocs",
         maxDepth: 2
      }
   }
] )
```

If you want to have more recursion level, change `maxDepth`. This search will put the resulting documents under `otherDocs`.

Comment: That won't work since you're trying to use HDP_Topics as a "path" (you're telling mongo to use current document's HDP_Topics property, but that's not what is happening here. HDP_Topics will be treated as a variable, but that variable isn't defined, so this will error out, or not work (not sure which)

Comment: Thanks @ParthThakkar for the correction, I updated my answer.

Comment: thanks for the response but $graphLookup is not supported by Stitch yet... Which makes things... Interesting.
https://docs.mongodb.com/stitch/mongodb/actions/collection.aggregate/

Comment: True, I didn't see that, sorry. Then you are left with wrapping it up in a recursive function.. That also gives you more control, if that is of any consolation.

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but I couldn't see any other alternative. So this is what I did in the end for a quick fix. Hopefully the aggregation functions (thanks @enys) will be implemented soon.

```
function getDataByTitle(title){
    try{
      var deferred = $q.defer();
      var docs = db.collection("articles").find({title:title}).asArray().then(
        docs => {
          var newData = [[docs[0]]];
          var docsLength = $rootScope.articlesToCompare;
          for(let i=1, p = Promise.resolve(); i < docsLength; i++){
            p = p.then(_ => new Promise(resolve => {
                newData.push(db.collection("articles").find({curid:docs[0].cosineArray[i]}).asArray());
                resolve();
                if(i==docsLength-1) deferred.resolve(newData);
            }));
          }
        }
      );
      return deferred.promise;
    } catch(err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
 }
```

Note: I changed from 'HDP_Topics' to 'cosineArray'. Also docsLength is predefined, which just works as a $limit alternative, seeing as I'm using multiple queries I can't defined this in the query itself.

The result is an array of arrays of articles. You can see it in action here: [unitroll.me](http://www.unitroll.me) , using the search bar on the top-right.